# Is there a way to send embed messages through DMs?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making bot in the discord.py, that can ban kick, or anything else. I'm stuck at point where it should send embed message when user get kicked, and I get some syntax errors ({
"resource": "it's private",
"owner": "python",
"code": "syntax-error",
"severity": 8,
"message": "invalid syntax (, line 64)",
"source": "pylint",
"startLineNumber": 64,
"startColumn": 22,
"endLineNumber": 64,
"endColumn": 22
})

I couldn't find anything in the internet...

````
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member :discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await client.get_user(member)
    await user.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=f"You have been banned from {ctx.message.guild.name}.", desctription=False, color=0xff6161)
                    embed.add_field(name=f"Reason: {reason}"))```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should edit it to the following:

```
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member :discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await client.get_user(member)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"You have been banned from {ctx.message.guild.name}.", color=0xff6161)
    embed.add_field(name="Reason: ", value = reason)
    await user.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# create the embed
embed = discord.Embed(title=f"You have been banned from {ctx.message.guild.name}.", color=0xff6161)
    embed.add_field(name="Reason: {reason}")

# send member the embed
await member.send(embed=embed)
```